Tor Browser won't start on Fedora i3
For some reason I cannot start the Tor browser on Fedora i3. I've tried installing it through terminal as per the instructions from the official website (cd into the tow-browser directory and then ./start-tor-browser.desktop, after that the terminal returns "Launching './Browser/start-tor-browser --detach'..." but doesn't actually launch anything) and from the file manager GUI (clicking the start-tor-broswer.desktop file) but nothing works nor do I get specific error messages. The browser GUI itself does not launch, it doesn't show up as a task either. Did someone encounter similar issues?

How do you know it's not already running? Do you have an Internet connection? (How do you know?) How exactly do you start tor from the command line (copy and paste, no screenshot). Have you configured it appropriately? How? Were you following a tutorial? If so please include a link to it here and explain where you're up to. Remember to edit your question to add this information. Please do not add it here in the comments. Make it easy for people to read and understand your question.
